# gcc <brace-enclosed initializer list> error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04

```
enum RoadType { unclassified, service, residential, tertiary, secondary, primary };
    static unordered_map<string,RoadType> const road_type_string_map = {
      { "unclassified", RoadType::unclassified },
      { "service", RoadType::service },
      { "residential", RoadType::residential },
      { "tertiary", RoadType::tertiary },
      { "secondary", RoadType::secondary },
      { "primary", RoadType:primary }
    };
```

The code above compiles on Ubuntu 20.04, but on 22.04 I get error:

```
sim.h:276:1: error: could not convert ‘{{"unclassified", unclassified}, {"service", service}, {"residential", residential}, {"tertiary", tertiary}, {"secondary", secondary}, {"primary", primary}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, RoadType>’
  276 | };
```

**makefile** uses "g++ -std=c++17  -Wall -g"

[EDIT]

What's interesting, in the same sim.h I have similar declaration, which compiles fine:

```
enum DriversSide {
  left = -1,
  right = 1
};

static unordered_map<string,DriversSide> const drivers_side_string_map = { 
  { "left", DriversSide::left }, 
  { "right", DriversSide::right }
};
```

Which makes me wonder if it depends on how the maps are used further in the code.

The code is inherited, so I don't have much knowledge about the internals, just trying to make it complie.

Comment: You're missing a colon in the last line.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Yes, I just found this.  Interesting that it builds on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: A typo in code (missing colon)